# XSLT: keeping whitespaces when copying attributes

Tags: xslt, vcproj

I'm trying to sort Microsoft Visual Studio's vcproj so that a diff would show something meaningful after e.g. deleting a file from a project. Besides the sorting, I want to keep everything intact, including whitespaces. The input looks like

*space*`<File`

*spacespace*`RelativePath="filename"`

*spacespace*`>`

...

The xslt fragment below can add the spaces around elements, but I can't find out how to deal with those around attributes, so my output looks like

*space*`<File RelativePath="filename">`

xslt I use for the msxsl 4.0 processor:

`<xsl:for-each select="File">`

`<xsl:sort select="@RelativePath"/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()[1]"/>`

`<xsl:copy>`

`<xsl:for-each select="text()|@*">`

`<xsl:copy/>`

`</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 1):

Those spaces are *always* insignificant in XML, and I believe that there is no option to control this behavior in a general way for any XML/XSLT library.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT works on a tree representation of the input XML. Many of the irrelevant detail of the original XML has been abstracted away in this tree - for example the order of attributes, insignificant whitespace between attributes, or the distinction between " and ' as an attribute delimiter. I can't see any conceivable reason for wanting to write a program that treats these distinctions as significant.

Comment: I would say that not even an **XML parser** do care about attributes order or space between as per the specs.